# Why do I need a DLL to use sqlite3?

Tags: c, dll, sqlite, dependencies

I have a program in C. I need to use a SQLite library to read data from a database.

When I include `sqlite3.h` to my source file I get `unresolved symbol` errors on `sqlite3` functions.

If I add `lib` file as library I don't get any error but program requires `sqlite3.dll` to run.

I already tried to play with compiler settings but nothing changed.

SQLite is written in C and my program is also C. Why do I need a DLL file to use SQLite?

How can I remove the DLL dependency.

I'm using MCVS2015 community edition IDE.

Comment: Because you are using the DLL version of sqlite?

Comment: Source code isn't same? How can i find static version of sqlite?

Comment: How did you get sqlite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [recommended](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html) way of compiling SQLite is to [download](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) the amalgamation source code file (`sqlite3.c`), and to add it to your project.